# Split a list of 'dd.mm.yyyy hh' strings into four seperate lists of integers

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I'm very new to programming. I've tried to search the website for similar problems, but can't find the information I need.

I have a list that contains multiple strings showing year, month, day and hour. I need to split this list into four lists of years, months, days and hours. The values have to be integers in the four lists.

The time format is: 'dd.mm.yyyy hh', example: '01.11.2020 02'

I'm able to split the string '01.11.2020 02' using this code:

```
timeStamp = '01.11.2020 02'

def getYear(timeStampStr):
    yearStr = timeStampStr[6:10]
    year = int(yearStr)
    return year
def getMonth(timeStampStr):
    monthStr = timeStampStr[3:5]
    month = int(monthStr)
    return month
def getDay(timeStampStr):
    dayStr = timeStampStr[0:2]
    day = int(dayStr)
    return day
def getHour(timeStampStr):
    hourStr = timeStampStr[11:13]
    hour = int(hourStr)
    return hour
```

I can then get the wanted result with:

```
print(getMonth(timeStamp))
```

However, this doesnt work when timeStamp is a list;

```
timeStamp = ['01.11.2020 00:00', '01.11.2020 01:00', '01.11.2020 02:00', etc].
```

What can I do to split it into four?

Comment: check out the builtin [`datetime` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Comment: for a DIY solution without any big changes in the code just define a class and add the functions as methods

Answer (score 1):

For list type you can use `map` like this

```
timeStamp = ['01.11.2020 00:00', '01.11.2020 01:00', '01.11.2020 02:00']
print(list(map(getMonth, timeStamp)))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use split function to divide the string and then label them

```
timeStamp.split('.')
```